# event delegation in vanilla js not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement event delegation is vanilla js, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click hold pinch', expandEventDel);
    function expandEventDel(event){
        if($(event.target).is('.dataCard') || $(event.target).parentsUntil(this).is('.dataCard')){
            alert("clicked, held, or pinched");
         }
    }
```

Comment: You have jQuery selectors in there, are you using jQuery?

Comment: ^^ What he said, you're mixing things up here, adding multiple events to addEventListener, using jQuery functions etc. Are you using jQuery or not ?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I can use jQuery for everything except the event listening.

Comment: @adeneo I can use jQuery for everything except the event listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to make easy event attachments, since `addEventListener` only accepts one event.

```
var events = ["click","hold","pinch"];
for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('main').addEventListener(events[i], expandEventDel);
}
```

Although since you already obviously have jquery loaded, you might as well use it, no?

Oh, and `alert` shouldn't be used as a debug statement. Just a protip there.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla `addEventListener` can only take a single event type.